# My Calculated Field with a nested IF(OR) statement is returning error

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula, formula

I am trying to input an email address into a calculated field with the following formula (I have replaced proprietary information with generic information in this formula):

```
=IF(OR([Customer Name]="Company A","Company B","Company C","Company D","Company E"),"user@solutions.com",IF(OR([Customer Name]="Company F","Company G","Company H","Company I","Company J","user2@solutions.com"))
```

The calculated field is set at a single line of text and I have ensured that the items in quotation from the Customer Name field match the drop down options for that field exactly by copying and pasting them.

It is returning `#Value!`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula:

```
=IF(OR([Customer Name]="Company A", [Customer Name]="Company B", [Customer Name]="Company C", [Customer Name]="Company D", [Customer Name]="Company E"), "user@solutions.com", IF(OR([Customer Name]="Company F", [Customer Name]="Company G", [Customer Name]="Company H", [Customer Name]="Company I", [Customer Name]="Company J"), "user2@solutions.com", ""))
```

**Microsoft documentation**:

1. [OR function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/or-function-9a2a1cca-696f-4d19-a959-3943babd076f)
2. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

Comment: Still getting the #Value! error.

Comment: Can you please share the latest formula you are using? It will be easier to answer your question. If possible also share the column settings of [Customer Name] field.

Comment: =IF(OR([Customer Name]="A",[Customer Name]="B",[Customer Name]="C”, [Customer Name]="D",[Customer Name]="E"),"user1@solutions.com",IF(OR([Customer Name]="F",[Customer Name]="G",[Customer Name]="H",[Customer Name]="I",[Customer Name]="J",[Customer Name]="K",[Customer Name]="L",[Customer Name]="M",[Customer Name]="N",[Customer Name]="O",[Customer Name]="P",[Customer Name]="Q",[Customer Name]="R"),"user2@vcomsolutions.com","")).

Comment: Customer Name is a Choice Field with a drop down menu to choose from

Comment: Your formula seems fine. You can add maximum 30 conditions inside single OR function. so make sure you are not adding more than that. Also, try adding double quotes  (`"`) around value manually, sometimes while copy pasting it gets converted to unsupported characters. like in formula in your above comment closing quote is different at: `[Customer Name]="C”`